# Distinct and order list LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Using Entity Framework, I have the following code that returns a list:

```
    private List<string> MyList()
    {
        using (MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities())
        {
            var myList= from a in ctx.Foo
                        orderby a.Bar
                        select a.Bar;

            return myList.ToList();
        }
    }
```

This works just fine, but I want a distinct list.  To achieve this, I tried the following code, adding .Distinct() to the select:

```
    private List<string> MyList()
    {
        using (MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities())
        {
            var myList= from a in ctx.Foo
                        orderby a.Bar
                        select a.Bar.Distinct();

            return myList.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, this new code results in an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumberable(char))' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(string)'

I then tried THIS code, which does give me a distinct list, but now it appears the orderby is not working as the results are unsorted:

```
    private List<string> MyList()
    {
        using (MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities())
        {
            var myList= (from a in ctx.Foo
                        orderby a.Bar
                        select a.Bar).Distinct();

            return myList.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Any ideas to return a distinct AND sorted list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
private List<string> MyList()
{
    using (MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities())
    {
        var myList= ctx.Foo.Select(a => a.Bar).Distinct().OrderBy(a => a);

        return myList.ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An efficient way to do this would be to use a groupby

```
private List<string> MyList()
{
    using (MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities())
        return ctx.Foo.GroupBy(a => a.Bar).Select(g => g.Key).OrderBy(a => a).ToList();
}
```

You can test it in linqpad like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var Foo = Enumerable.Range(0,50).Select(i => new { id = i, Bar = i%3}).ToList();
    var myList= Foo.GroupBy(a => a.Bar).Select(g => g.Key).OrderBy(a => a).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(myList);
}
```